# .NET Core - Entity framework - FindAsync does not return related tables

Tags: .net, entity

(**I found answers to this, but none of them are compatible with my code**)

- savind the objects works, and **related tables are populated upon FK's**

```
_context.Partners.Add(partnerCreation.Partner);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

- but getting back the main table **does only return that table, not the linked tables**

```
var partner = await _context.Partners.FindAsync(id);
```

my model beeing defined that way:

```
public class Partner
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public User ModificationUser { get; set; }
    public RetributionPlan retributionPlan { get; set; }
}
```

I expect **ModificationUser** and **retributionPlan** to be retrieved too

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an include statement

```
var partner = await _context.Partners.Include(p => p.ModificationUser).Include(p => p.retributionPlan).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

If you need nested fields use ThenInclude

Comment: yesss !!! what do you mean by nested fields ? so far my objects are present and populated in the main object

Comment: If for instance User had an object, let's call it Address, then you would have to do something like this to include the address object:
`var partner = await _context.Partners.Include(p => p.ModificationUser).ThenInclude(m => m.Address).Include(p => p.retributionPlan).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);`

Comment: can you help me out on this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63790062/entity-framework-not-using-linked-table-id-in-insert-query

Answer (score 0):

I prefer adding Id as a property too.
So your class will be:

```
public class Partner
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public User ModificationUser { get; set; }
    public int ModificationUserId { get; set; }
    public int retributionPlanId { get; set; }
    public RetributionPlan retributionPlan { get; set; }
}
```

So you can call either

```
await _context.Partners.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
```

or

```
await _context.Partners.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p=> p.Id == id).Include(x=>x.ModificationUser);
```