# Entity Framework - not using linked table id in insert query

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have 2 tables, Foo and Bar, **Foo has a link to a Bar record**

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar SomeBar{ get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

the SQL table (**with the FK constraint between the two tables**):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] ( 
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [SomeBarId] INT         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Foo_Bar] FOREIGN KEY ([SomeBarId]) REFERENCES [Bar]([Id]),
);
```

when I save the table, **Entity does not use SomeBarId in the query**, producing an error, while I have set a **FK constraint between the two tables**

*Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SomeBarId ', table 'dbo.foo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.*

**how do I tell entity to use the field SomeBarId when doing the insert ?**

```
var someBar = await _context.Bars.FindAsync(1); // fetch a Bar record

foo.SomeBar = someBar; // linking the objects

_context.Foo.Add(foo);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I expect EF to get someBar.Id and use it in the query when inserting Foo in DB

thanks for the time you'll spend helping me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding ForeignKey attribute in class Foo and remove the nullable Id in Bar

```
public class Foo
{
    [ForeignKey("Bar")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Bar SomeBar{ get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @phil123456 also are you using code-first approach?

Comment: I recently deactivated the tracking cos it was causing errors, could this be related?

Comment: ok I think it works but it tries to insert Bar into the DB while it's already there...'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table Bar'

Comment: Won't it be fine if you auto-generate the Id in Bar table? You are adding Id value from outside (which is not auto-generated) environment and that's why you are getting that error. Either make the Id auto-generated or you can make it nullable,

Comment: yeah it figures the BAr is not part of the Foo class actualy, it's something that should be linked but not part of it, so, I'll deal with it manualy