# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '...', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type '...'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

**What am I doing?** 
I am trying using two modal in one view.

**What's the problem?** 
When run give this error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ProgramaEstagio.Models.Person', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ProgramaEstagio.Models.RegisterViewModel'.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)
```

**Part of "PersonController.cs":**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ProgramaEstagio.Data;
using ProgramaEstagio.Models;

namespace ProgramaEstagio.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PersonController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Person
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Person.ToListAsync());
        }
        // GET: Person/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var person = await _context.Person.FindAsync(id);
            if (person == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(person);
        }

        // POST: Person/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,FullName,BirthDate,sex")] Person person)
        {
            if (id != person.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(person);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PersonExists(person.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(person);
        }
```

**RegisterViewModel.cs:**

```cs
namespace ProgramaEstagio.Models
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml:**

```html
@model ProgramaEstagio.Models.RegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Person</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Person.ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Person.FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Person.FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Person.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Person.BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Person.BirthDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Person.BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Person.sex" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Person.sex" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Person.sex" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <h4>Address</h4>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Address.ID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.Country" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address.Country" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.Complement" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address.Complement" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.Complement" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.Distric" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address.Distric" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.Distric" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.City" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address.City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.State" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address.State" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.State" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Address.PersonID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Address.PersonID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PersonID"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Address.PersonID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

What I have to do? please help me. If need more information, ask please. And sorry for any error orthography and grammar I am studing English.
Project Link: https://github.com/vitorhugo1207/Sys-Vacina/tree/EditPagePersonAdress

Edit:
**AddressController.cs:**

```cs
        // GET: Addresse/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            RegisterViewModel register = new RegisterViewModel();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var address = await _context.Address.FindAsync(id);
            if (address == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["PersonID"] = new SelectList(_context.Person, "ID", "FullName", address.PersonID);
            register.Address = address;
            return View(register);
        }

        // POST: Addresse/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Country,Complement,Distric,City,State,PersonID")] Address address)
        {
            if (id != address.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(address);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!AddressExists(address.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["PersonID"] = new SelectList(_context.Person, "ID", "FullName", address.PersonID);
            return View(address);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is happening on this line: `return View(person);`. You are sending a `Model` of type Person but you need to send a `Model` of RegisterViewModel. You need to send the correct `Model` to your `View`:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        RegisterViewModel register = new RegisterViewModel();
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var person = await _context.Person.FindAsync(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        register.Person = person;
        var address = await _context.Address.FindAsync(id);
        if (address == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        register.Address = address;
        return View(register);
    }
```

Comment: It's doesn't returning data to Address fields, only for Persons. There's a way for return both?

Comment: @IkkiArtz What is your logic to get the `Address` field? You need to define your logic to get the address and then set it to `register.Address`

Comment: I put it in question. I should call `AddressController` in `PersonController` before the **return** or create a function in `PersonController` for get the data? how I should do it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @IkkiArtz You can create a data access layer from where you can get your data as per your context. You need to show more code on how you are getting the `Person` data and what is the structure of your `Person` model.

Comment: I push the branch to GitHub because would stay unorganized here. Link: https://github.com/vitorhugo1207/Sys-Vacina/tree/EditPagePersonAdress

Comment: @IkkiArtz It seems that you have `Edit` view for your `Address` and `Person` controller. Then why do you need a common `Model` for them? Just separate your models as per the respective `View` for each `Controller`. If you need the data for `Address` in your `Person` controller, you can simply call the logic that you are doing in your `Address` controller. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The `address` arrive `null`, it doesn't continue after `if (address == null)`. Why it doesn't getting data from `Address`? Thanks you so far.

Comment: @IkkiArtz I am not sure on how have you defined your context. As per the specs: If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store. Otherwise, a request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary key values and this entity, if found, is attached to the context and returned. If no entity is found in the context or the store, then null is returned . You can read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: `Id` return the `ID` user, but `FindAsync(id)` doesn't looking for column `PersonID` (`ID` user in Address table) in `Address` instead it look for `ID` of Addresses. How do `FindAsync()` look for column `PersonID` instead `ID` of Addresses? For example something like `FindAsync(PersonID=id)`. Thanks you so far.

Comment: @IkkiArtz You need to `Include` the `Address` entity when you are finding the `Person` data. You can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722982/net-core-entity-framework-findasync-does-not-return-related-tables

Answer (score 2):

You essentially made a promise to C# that you would send a model of type `RegisterViewModel`, when you wrote this:

```
@model ProgramaEstagio.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

But then you actually sent a Person instead:

```
var person = await _context.Person.FindAsync(id);
...
return View(person);
```

It doesn't really matter what these two things are, *so long as they agree*; if you upgrade/change the type in one place (like the cshtml), you have to change it everywhere else (like the controller `View(..)` calls) to ensure they remain in agreement with each other

Comment: It's doesn't returning data to Address fields, only for Persons. There's a way for return both?

Comment: You make a registerviewmodel, you put the person and the address in the registerviewmodel, and then you return the registerviewmodel